# shift cells down add a row in word not shift cell down

Tags: microsoft-word

I choose shift cells down but it adds a row in word not shift cell down.
[image]

[image]

I want some thing like this. only shift one cell to down. when i choose shift cell right, it works fine.
[image]

Comment: What result did you want? Just a new cell in the middle of a row? Or are you just trying to move the text down and not insert a cell at all?

Comment: I want only one cell shift to down not to add one new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. See the [Office Support page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-cell-row-or-column-to-a-table-b030ef77-f219-4998-868b-ba85534867f1) regarding this functionality.

> **Shift cells right**
>
> Insert a cell and move all other cells in that row to the right.
>
> *NOTE   Word does not insert a new column. This may result in a row*
>   *that has more cells than the other rows.*
>
> **Shift cells down**
>
> Insert a cell and move the existing cells down one row. ***A new row is***
>   ***added at the bottom of the table.***
>
> **Insert entire row**
>
> Insert a row above the cell that you clicked in.
>
> **Insert entire column**
>
> Insert a column to the left of the cell that you clicked in.

Comment: so the Shift cells down and Insert entire row are same. the difference is place of row.

Comment: Correct, insert row places above your cell, shift down puts a new row at the bottom of the table.